# Adding AVG(Price) into a mySQL query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following query

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM used ".$conditionString." ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $offset, $rec_limit";
```

But now I want to know also the average price of the returned rows

```
AVG(Price) AS PriceAverage
```

How to do this?

Comment: group by? roll up ? the question is not clear

Answer (score 2):

this should work for you:

```
$query = "SELECT *,AVG(Price) FROM used ".$conditionString." ORDER BY id DESC 
GROUP BY id WITH ROLLUP 
LIMIT $offset, $rec_limit";
```

demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4938f/1/0

Comment: thank you for this. Why we need the `group by id with rollup`?

Comment: to get the result of the price average

Comment: I am using `while($used = mysql_fetch_assoc($useds)) { ` to show the results. How can I make use of the average price one time only?

Comment: check for where the id is blank\null